# How to formulate a single cell in multiple ways, according to other fields being populated or not?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get a spreadsheet working in Google Sheets and I'm having a hard time finding a formula that will fit my needs, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 | Cell 7 | Cell 8 |

To be specific, I need Cell 2 to check Cell 1 to see if its empty. If 1 is empty, 2 can stay empty. Once 1 has input, 2 needs to return a specific time.

While Cell 3 should check Column 4 to see if its empty. If 4 is Empty, 3 can stay empty. Once 4 has input, 3 needs to return a specific time.

ALSO, if BOTH 1 & 4 have input, then BOTH 2 & 3 need to stay empty.

I also need it to be repeatable down a table of cells, which is why I've included a second row.

I have gotten the first part working using =IF(A1<>"", "8:00", "") which works for both Cell 2 and Cell 3 to check the outer cells, but I can't find a way to get the second part to compound and check if both cells have input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? For B2:

> =IF(A2="","",IF(D2="","8:00",""))

For C2:

> =IF(D2="","",IF(A2="","16:00",""))

You can set them as array formulas, you put them in B2 and C2 respectively and they'll drag automatically to the end.

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",IF(D2:D="","8:00","")))
>
> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="","",IF(A2:A="","16:00","")))

Comment: This could work, my only question would be how do I compound these with the second part? If both A & D have input, both C & D should be empty.

Comment: Have you tried it?? It should already do it! In the first formula it sees if A2 is empty, B2 will be empty, B2 is empty. If it isn't, then it checks if D2 is empty, if D2 is empty then B2 will be 8.00. If it isn't, then B2 will be empty

Comment: All possible cases are in those two columns (one for B and one for C) ;)

Comment: I stand corrected Martín, this is exactly what I was looking for. Lol. I hadn't tried it when I first replied. It works exactly as I was wanting it to. Massive thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated.